# Some programs not found when used with sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo

I just installed [go](http://golang.org/) to `/usr/local/go`, and in `~/.bashrc` added this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Now `go` works from the command line, but `sudo go` gives me:

```
$ sudo go
sudo: go: command not found
~
$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/benjamin/algs4/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo echo $PATH`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo` command has `env_keep` and `env_reset` parameters in `sudoers` file.

You have to either edit your env_keep setting or use `sudo -E`.

Comment: On my Debian-9 system `sudo -E` does not keep the `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the file /etc/sudoers. Add the desired paths to the following line:

> Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

example:

> Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've security policy setup for your PATH by the following command:

```
$ sudo sudo -V | grep PATH
Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

If so, either disable it or add it there by `sudo visudo`.

See: [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8646/21471) at Unix SE