# sudo command not found

Tags: sudo

I have a curious problem. I've just installed a program named undervolt. When I launch the program from command line typing "undervolt" everything goes fine. However if I type "sudo undervolt" I get the error "sudo: undervolt: command not found". I would avoid using sudo, but in this case I really need it.
How can I manage to use the program with sudo?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the `undervolt` executable was installed to a location that is not on sudo's `secure_path` but is in your user's `PATH`

Comment: And that you should read `man sudo;man sudoers` and use the full path to `undervolt`, e.g. `sudo $(type -p undervolt)`

Comment: Could you explain me the syntax of sudo $(type -p undervolt) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some programs not found when used with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118263/some-programs-not-found-when-used-with-sudo)